# Javascript regex for groups' single letter or word with or without space

Tags: javascript, regex

not sure if my methods achieving what I wanted to match the words which wanted to match on [Test sample](http://regexr.com/3du48), probably anyone can suggest a better way on this?

matching words and symbols with or without spaces

> al, alla, and, 's, dell', #, &, (, ), \,/

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please show what you tried, what it does, and what you expected it to do.

Comment: You can shorten your regex to this [`\B[-&#\/\\()]\B|\bdell'\B|\B's\b|\b(?:al(?:la?)?|and|bodegas?)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/fK5tP1/1)